# How to fix error at Welcome Page of React App after deploying it on firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, deployment, hosting, firebase-hosting

I made a React project, and it is working locally on my machine. But After I deployed it on Firebase, it is showing me this page:

[image: some-page]

I followed these steps to deploy app on Firebase:

1. `npm install -g firebase-tools`
2. `firebase login`
3. `firebase init`

3.1) made a build folder instead of public.

3.2)  Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to `/index.html`)? (y/N) `Yes`

3.3) Set up automatic builds and deploys with GitHub? (y/N) `No`

4. `npm run build`
5. `firebase deploy`

---

My folder structure is like this.

[image: directory]

And my `firebase.json` folder is like this:

```json
    {
      "hosting": {
        "public": "build",
        "ignore": [
          "firebase.json",
          "**/.*",
          "**/node_modules/**"
        ],
        "rewrites": [
          {
            "source": "**",
            "destination": "/index.html"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong, and how should I correct it?